VerilatedFstC variables wrapped with std::unique_ptr crashed when the program exits
I'm working with verilator using c++, I wrote the following test code:
#include "Vmux_2_1.h"
#include <memory>
#include <verilated.h>
#include <verilated_fst_c.h>

std::unique_ptr<VerilatedFstC> trace = std::make_unique<VerilatedFstC>();

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<VerilatedContext> kContext =
      std::make_unique<VerilatedContext>();
  std::unique_ptr<Vmux_2_1> kTop = std::make_unique<Vmux_2_1>();

  kContext->traceEverOn(true);
  kTop->trace(trace.get(), 99);
  trace->open("waveform.fst");
  trace->close();

  return 0;
}

The Vmux_2_1 is a multiplexer class that verilator gernerated.
This segment code seems do nothing actual work, but it crashed finally.
But if I move the trace into the main() function, everything works well, here is the code:
#include "Vmux_2_1.h"
#include <memory>
#include <verilated.h>
#include <verilated_fst_c.h>

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<VerilatedContext> kContext =
      std::make_unique<VerilatedContext>();
  std::unique_ptr<VerilatedFstC> trace = std::make_unique<VerilatedFstC>();
  std::unique_ptr<Vmux_2_1> kTop = std::make_unique<Vmux_2_1>();

  kContext->traceEverOn(true);
  kTop->trace(trace.get(), 99);
  trace->open("waveform.fst");
  trace->close();

  return 0;
}

I tried clang++ and g++ to compile this project but both failed, I don't know what's wrong with it.
I printed the debug intfo:
[New Thread 0x7ffff7a006c0 (LWP 519617)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff70006c0 (LWP 519618)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff66006c0 (LWP 519619)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5c006c0 (LWP 519620)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff52006c0 (LWP 519621)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff48006c0 (LWP 519622)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff3e006c0 (LWP 519623)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff34006c0 (LWP 519624)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff2a006c0 (LWP 519625)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff20006c0 (LWP 519627)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff16006c0 (LWP 519628)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff0c006c0 (LWP 519629)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff02006c0 (LWP 519630)]
[New Thread 0x7fffef8006c0 (LWP 519631)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeee006c0 (LWP 519632)]
[Thread 0x7ffff7a006c0 (LWP 519617) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff66006c0 (LWP 519619) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff5c006c0 (LWP 519620) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff70006c0 (LWP 519618) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff52006c0 (LWP 519621) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff3e006c0 (LWP 519623) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff34006c0 (LWP 519624) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff48006c0 (LWP 519622) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff2a006c0 (LWP 519625) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff20006c0 (LWP 519627) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff0c006c0 (LWP 519629) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff02006c0 (LWP 519630) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff16006c0 (LWP 519628) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffef8006c0 (LWP 519631) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffeee006c0 (LWP 519632) exited]

Thread 1 "trace" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ccafc6 in std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer (this=0x7fffffffd1d0, __first=0x4ef060, __last=0x4ef46f) at ../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/list.cc:102
102       __last->_M_prev->_M_next  = this;



Update, here is an minimal reproducible example, but first you need to set-up verilator environment:
mux2_1.v:
module mux2_1 (
  a, b, s, y
);
  input a, b, s;
  output y;

  assign y = (~s & a) | (s & b);
endmodule
// A new line is required here

trace.cpp
#include "Vmux2_1.h"
#include <memory>
#include <verilated.h>
#include <verilated_fst_c.h>

std::unique_ptr<VerilatedFstC> trace = std::make_unique<VerilatedFstC>();

int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<VerilatedContext> kContext =
      std::make_unique<VerilatedContext>();
  std::unique_ptr<Vmux2_1> kTop = std::make_unique<Vmux2_1>();

  kContext->traceEverOn(true);
  kTop->trace(trace.get(), 99);
  trace->open("waveform.fst");
  trace->close();

  return 0;
}

Use the following command to compile it:
 verilator --cc --exe --build --trace-fst -j 4 -Wall trace.cpp mux2_1.v

It will create a obj_dir as the output directory, as well as an executable file Vmux2_1, just use ./obj_dir/Vmux2_1 to run it.

In the first version, it seems likely that trace accesses an object after its lifetime has ended in the VerilatedFstC destructor but it's hard to say for sure without seeing a [mre].

Sidenote: Why are your using pointers instead of regular automatic variables?

"If a VerilatedContext is not created prior to creating a model, a default global one is created automatically." and "The Verilated:: methods [...], call VerilatedContext methods using the default global VerilatedContext. (Technically they operate on the last one used by a given thread.) If you are using multiple simulation contexts you should not use the Verilated:: methods, and instead always use VerilatedContext methods called on the appropriate VerilatedContext object." so it seems to me that the mistake is that you create the VerilatedContext after the VerilatedFstC

@Ted Lyngmo Yes, you are right, I just follow the verilator turotial examples where using ponters to create these objects, that I don't realize to use automatic variables simply, so I'll try it.

Using automatic variables does not solve the problem. It was just a sidenote. Instead, create your VerilatedContext first and see if that helps.

@Ted Lyngmo Actually, I create the VerilatedContext before VerilatedFstC globally, it failed, but even though I declare the VerilatedFstC before VerilatedContex in main(), it works ok.

"it failed" - How? "even though I declare the VerilatedFstC before VerilatedContex in main(), it works ok" - That could be because the default global VerilatedContext will be used for the VerilatedFstC that you create first in that case as I wrote above.

I mean It got the same segment fault error while running as I described in the debug info,     if i create VerilatedContext before VerilatedFstC globally, like this:
std::unique_ptr<VerilatedContext> kContext =     std::make_unique<VerilatedContext>(); std::unique_ptr<VerilatedFstC> trace = std::make_unique<VerilatedFstC>(); 

To clarify: If you create VerilatedFstC globally, the global VerilatedContex will get destroyed before the VerilatedFstC is destroyed. if you create VerilatedFstC in main the global VerilatedContex will get destroyed after  theVerilatedFstC is destroyed. I think it's important to make the context live longer than the VerilatedFstC since it's referenced by the VerilatedFstC.

Anyway, is there a reason why you create any of them as global variables? Why not create them in main?

Oh, I see, does any manual explains why the VerilatedContext will get destroyed first?
I think the VerilatedContext is created first globally, so it should be destroyed second

That's because I have some global functions to manipulate those variables, so it is convenient to use them, that i don't have to pass the argument

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
